# return to filemanger/gallery after sharing a image to my app

Tags: android, intentfilter

i am using intent-filter to share images to my application.
the uploading Activity is (B) and the main Activity in my app is (A).
so the images sent from filemanger/gallery to Activity (B) then the user click upload and i kill the (B) Activity with

```
    finish();
```

and i am using

```
    onActivityResult()
```

method to check if the user came from the uploading Activity and end the main Activity (A) with the finish() function.
now i killed my app but the system take the user to the home or the apps list.
i want the system take the user back to the filemanger or the gallery to share more photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add a attribute to the Activity in the manifest file
you have to change the way of lunching the Activity
add this code in the Activity tag

```
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

more info : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode